# Jquery Изменить текст нескольких #id в одной строке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть Такой Код, тут Jquery сначала меняет html #book, а потом меняет html #book2, можно ли записать все в одну строку ? Т.К чтобы он сразу менял и #book и #book2 на разные значения, а не поочереди.

```
  var litem = 'TEST';
  var litem2 = 'TEST2';

  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#book").html(litem);
          $("#book2").html(litem2);

  });
```

попробовал так, но так он 2ую переменную не видит, а меняет оба #id на 1 переменную.

```
  $("#book, #book2").html(litem, litem2);
```

Comment: "сразу, a не поочереди" - объясните - зачем Вам это нужно

Answer (score 0):

```js
var litem1 = 'TEST1';
var litem2 = 'TEST2';
var litem3 = 'TEST3';
var litem4 = 'TEST4';

var els = document.getElementsByClassName('books');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, (el, index) => $('#book_' + (++index)).html(window['litem'+index]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="book_1" class="books"></div>
<div id="book_2" class="books"></div>
<div id="book_3" class="books"></div>
<div id="book_4" class="books"></div>
```

Сработает, если переменные `litem1/litem2/litem3/litem4` в глобальной области видимости `window`